# viewpager with elements being removed on swipe

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am calling an api that returns json. I parse the json into an arraylist of objects. I have a class that i created to randomly select an element from the list and remove it and display it in the viewpager. I have the viewpager and pageradapter set up and asyncloader to create the dataset. I get a runtime exception with the following. If i change the getCount() to return a static number then it works as i want it to but it doesnt accomplish my requirements that i listed below.

```
The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 14, found: 12 Pager id
```

I totally understand why it is happening. The following code is why.

random element class: this method provides the random object i want to display in the viewpager at the same time removing from the list so i do not retrieve it again.

```
public T spin() throws IllegalStateException, NullPointerException {
    if (list == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("A list has not been set.");
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        int i = rand.nextInt(list.size());
        T b = list.remove(i);
        return b;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("There are no more elements left. Please query more.") ;
    }
}
```

This is my inner pageradapter class - **r** is the object of the randomelement class:

```
     private class RPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public RPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return r.size();
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(context);


        mViewHolder.setItem(r.spin());

        container.addView(mViewHolder);

        return mViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

What im trying to accomplish is the following:

1. The user can only swipe forward (to the left) thus the spin method will be invoked correctly. (priority)
2. When the the spin method returns an exception the loader is called to load more data. (not a priority right now)
3. The user cannot be allowed to swipe right because the functionality of the app is for the user to only see a random element once (which the randomelement class accomplishes) so i need the viewpager to understand to only move in one direction meaning a new random element is displayed.

Please let me know if there is a different way that i can implement the above or point me in the right android apis to use.

Answer (score 0):

> A call to the PagerAdapter method startUpdate(ViewGroup) indicates
>   that the contents of the ViewPager are about to change. One or more
>   calls to instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int) and/or destroyItem(ViewGroup,
>   int, Object) will follow, and the end of an update will be signaled by
>   a call to finishUpdate(ViewGroup).

Therefore, you should only perform your update in the list in `finishUpdate(ViewGroup)`

forget about your whole spin structure, try something like this, pseudo code only:

```
private class RPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<T> items;

    public RPagerAdapter(Context context, List<T> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(context);


        mViewHolder.setItem(items.get(position));

        container.addView(mViewHolder);
        container.setTag(String.valueOf(position));

        return mViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
         int position = Integer.parseInt(container.getTag());
         //remove all items before position
         //add items at the end if you want
         notifyDataSetChanged();
         viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

Comment: So from this code you are saying that i should modify my list object inside finishUpdate and that the current item is always set to page 0 which means that the user cannot swipe right?

Comment: The main idea is to modify the object on finishUpdate, and set current item back to the right item, I think I have some misunderstanding on how the items should be changed

Comment: i dont want to modify the item at all. I want to display the item (instantiateItem) and remove that item from the list. This way the item can never be shown again. I also want the next item that is displayed to always be the first page. This means that the user cannot swipe right (back) and only swipe left (forward)

Comment: then I think my understanding is almost correct, except that I reversed the swipe direction, do you still need any help?

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but is this what you mean.

`Override
    public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
         int position = Integer.parseInt(container.getTag());
         
items.remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();
         viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
    }`

Comment: No. you have to implement the comments by yourself, you have to remove those items you don't want to show again and add new pending items to the list, also you have to `setCurrentItem` to the correct position of the current showing item after the changes instead of using `0`

Comment: I think that is in the right direction. I tried it but since finishupdate is being invoked many times it does not work for this purpose. Thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem, sorry it didn't work, maybe you can try ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener instead, good luck

Comment: I decided to use a button with a click that imitates the viewpager swipe. It actually worked out better for my app.

Comment: Glad that you found a better alternative